# how to get shell scripts to run at startup on Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, network

There is a directory in System/Library for startup items I presume: StartupItems

I need to have a shell script that will configure ethernet interface at start up, with local network address and subnet mask. I need to do this because the
network preferences for configuring the ethernet interface will NOT set it
using manual settings. THIS appears to be a serious bug, or my installation
is bad.

I was given the advice to use  networksetup from the command line but that
will not configure the ethernet interface in such a way that the configurations will be there on reboot.

The script needs to do its work with root privileges, or with sudo, but I
am assuming that if it uses sudo, there will be a password dialog presented
at boot time when the boot process gets to that script.

(I have had enough experience with FreeBsd and Linux to find my way around
in the terminal, but not necessarily as it applies to Mac OSX)

Answer (score 20):

One way of doing it would be assigning the script a launchd service:

Create the shell script as usual. Then you can make a launchd service to run it at startup. Those are located at `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. These are in the XML property list format. Create another and populate it with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.example.app</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/bin/sh</string>
            <string>/path/to/script</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Change `com.example.app`, `/bin/sh` and `/path/to/script` as required.

The script will then run while the system is booting. If it runs too early, you can either write the script to try and do what it needs to do until it succeeds, or have it exit with a non-zero error code and add this to the property list before the `</dict>` line:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
     <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
     <false/>
</dict>
```

For more on OS X launch daemons and services, I suggest looking [here](http://launchd.info) for a nice quick-reference on making them, or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) for a more comprehensive reference on what launchd can do.

Comment: What do you call this plist document? And does the /path/to/script == /System/Library/StartupItems/script?

Comment: For the first question: The plist document's name generally uses what the Label key in the property list is set to (in this case, "com.example.app") with a .plist extension.

Comment: For the second question: That is correct, but the script should be moved elsewhere.

Comment: Your plist is malformed.  You need a Key: `<key>Program</key>` with the value `<string>/bin/sh</string>` and then `<key>ProgramArguments</key>` should just have the value `<string>/path/to/script</string>`

Comment: Actually, mine is wrong too: `<key>ProgramArguments</key>` needs to be an array..

Answer (score 19):

Some time ago I used cron to do just that. You can make an entry like this

```
@reboot /path/to/my/script
```

[More info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/crontab.5.html)

> Instead of the first five fields, one of eight special strings may appear:

```
       string          meaning
       ------          -------@reboot ------@reboot
       @reboot         Run once, at startup.
       @yearly         Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
       @annually       (same as @yearly)
       @monthly        Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
       @weekly         Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
       @daily          Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
       @midnight       (same as @daily)
       @hourly         Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
```

Comment: Very handy to know!

Comment: `cron` is not the right way to do this on OS X these days. Use LaunchAgent or LaunchDeamon instead (launchd). For more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html `Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd.`

Comment: `cron` is a lot easier to configure than `launchd`, though. Just compare the two answers in this thread to see what I mean. `cron` takes a single line in a single file, where `launchd` needs a script to describe the script you want run at boot.

Comment: @Dannid Kron is not sensitive to run duplication, queue buffering, and others. Though viable in this case, it's not always a skeleton key, nor is it an idiomatic solution.

Comment: Crontab is way better. It's quick and dirty and long established in the Unix world. I totally dig this @reboot keyword.

Comment: @macetw Ideally yes. And yes it is long established in the Unix world. However that may be it's deprecated in macOS and has been for some while. You never know with deprecated things: there may be a time that it's no longer supported. And yes *@reboot* is useful and it's something some other Unices have but still to recommend something that is deprecated is asinine. Unfortunate that it's deprecated? Yes. Especially for those of us who are old timers. But it's still the way it is. Much like the travesty that is systemd... But never mind that.

Comment: @sjosen, @macetw & @Dannid: is the `@reboot` cron option still working for you?  I have been using it successfully for a few years on my old (2012) MacbookPro (which cannot be upgraded beyond Catalina, now) and for the last 2 months I noticed my @reboot cron jobs are no longer run at boot :-( instead they have been running @monthly at 12:00am on the 1st of each month.  I wonder if its a bug, something weird about my system config (which is plenty weird) or if this @reboot feature was intentionally mapped to @monthly now...?

Comment: Correction: i just tested again, and my @reboot cron jobs _do_ appear to still be running at boot time!  One just wasn't sending email (probably because the internet or mail system wasn't available yet) but my ifconfig commands are bringing up the interfaces I needed this for so yay! Odd that they *also* seems to be running monthly too, but not an issue for me :-)

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at login hook script.

https://wiki.afp548.com/index.php/Login/Logout_Hooks_in_OS_X

Comment: A login hook is initiated by the loginwindow.app which is not the same as running a  script at startup.