# Run Script As A Service After Startup

Tags: macos, mac, startup

Recently I am trying to figure out how to run a `dotnet` service after my MacOS startup.

On Windows, I can install the [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/description) to run the script as a service. This script will be triggered whenever my computer starts up.

Inside the script contains the line of code like `dotnet RunMyService`

Am I allow to perform the same action in MacOS as well?

Comment: Why use .NET on macOS?

Comment: @JMY1000, there is a script I created by using `.NET`.  I need to run this script before I can continue my work on MacOS.

Comment: I'm a little confused to be honest, since Windows Services don't exist on macOS for obvious reasons. There's other parallels, but I'm not sure if they'd fit the purpose. What does you script do? Is the source available somewhere?

Comment: @JMY1000 the source only on my computer. I need to run `dotnet RunMyService` every single time before I start my projects. So I am thinking is there a way to run my scripts after startup.

Comment: [Have you taken a look at create a launchd service?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156288/how-to-get-shell-scripts-to-run-at-startup-on-yosemite) Also, could you maybe create a Gist with the source?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, via `launchd` -- you will have to use `launchctl` to configure applications on your mac to run via `launchd` (similar to Linux `systemd` or the Windows SCM.)

From another post, "There is no requirement that you use any Cocoa/Mac APIs to implement an agent/daemon, you could run any console app under launchd and the above would still remain true." ~ [SO#40952619](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994583/application-backgrounding-in-xamarin-mac/40952619#40952619)

You only need a plist and a script.

#### The Script

My advice is to place your script into `/usr/local/bin/` or similar, `chown` to root:wheel, and `chmod` to 755 making it an executable. Your script should contain the full path to `dotnet` and `cd` to the working folder of your service before starting execution. This is only an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/your/service/
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet MyService.dll
```

For the sake of this post, let's assume you saved this as `/usr/local/bin/launch-my-service.sh`:

```bsh
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/launch-my-service.sh
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/launch-my-service.sh
```

If you run this script manually it should successfully launch your service. Once confirmed, kill the process and create the PLIST.

#### The PLIST

For `launchd` wants a plist, take this as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>localhost.my-service</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/launch-my-service.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Save this to your home folder, launchctl will make a copy of it anyway. For the sake of this post, let's assume you saved this as `localhost.my-service.plist` to match the "Label" configured inside the plist (which is what `launchctl` will display.)

#### Configure `launchd`

Now we add the "service" to `launchd`, and start it:

```bsh
launchctl load localhost.my-service.plist # here we specify the plist file
launchctl list | grep localhost
launchctl start localhost.my-service # here we specify the "Label" configured in the plist file
```

It's beyond the scope of this Q&A, but, this creates an "Agent" (rather than a Daemon), which is a macOS/launchd specific concept. An "Agent" is an application which runs in the background whenever a user logs in to the macOS desktop. The Agent runs with the identity of the logged in user. The run state of an Agent may change depending on the logged in state of the user (may stop, tombstone, etc.) It is also possible to install as a "Daemon" which would run in the context of the system (rather than the logged in user), and which can be configured to run whether or not a user logs in. An example plist for configuring an "inetd-compatible daemon" can be found on [developer.apple.com "Creating `launchd` Jobs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

HTH someone else out there. Totally irrelevant if you're using `dotnet`, `java`, `lua`, or `python` macOS could care less.